# jsr-196 and retaining authenticated user

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

I implemented a JSR-196 authentication module.

It seems I need to save the user myself, so I put it in session after successful authentication.

Now, is it a problem with my implementation, or is it the way it is intended? Do I really need to check the session on every request?

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's intended this way. A jsr-196 module is responsible for those aspects.